# ionic item vue router pass metadata from template

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-router

Using IONIC 3 with Vue I would like to pass my object `p` to my router to access metadata later. I tried using tag `:meta` but it does not work:

route

```
{
  path: '/new',
  meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  component: () => import ('../views/New.vue')
},
```

app.vue

```
    <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" v-for="(p, i) in appPages" :key="i">
          <ion-item 
              @click="selectedIndex = i" 
              router-direction="root" 
              :router-link="p.url" 
              lines="none" 
              detail="false" 
              class="hydrated" 
              :meta=p
              :class="{ selected: selectedIndex === i }">
            <ion-icon slot="start" :ios="p.iosIcon" :md="p.mdIcon"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label class="pointer">{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </ion-list>
```

I can't access in template

template.vue

```
<ion-header :translucent="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button color="primary"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{ $route.meta }}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```